# QT : Capture to Buffer without saving to file

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qcamera

In my project I capture photo to buffer using `QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer` . But it also saves images to the file. Since I am planning to capture images continuously I want to prevent it from saving images to the file. Here is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
cam = new QCamera;
cam->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);

viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder;
viewfinder->show();
QCameraImageCapture *cap = new QCameraImageCapture(cam);
cap->setCaptureDestination(QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer);

cam->setViewfinder(viewfinder);


QObject::connect(cap, &QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured, [=] (int id, QImage img) {
    QByteArray buf;
    QBuffer buffer(&buf);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    img.save(&buffer, "BMP");


});

QObject::connect(cap, &QCameraImageCapture::readyForCaptureChanged, [=] (bool state) {
   if(state == true) {
       cam->searchAndLock();
       cap->capture();
       cam->unlock();
   }
});
cam->start();
```

}

Comment: Seems like your camera does not support capturing in buffer with Qt. Look at QCameraImageCapture::isCaptureDestinationSupported().

Comment: You can delete saved image every time after capturing or use OpenCV.

Comment: @SerhiyKulish Since this is a group Project we decided not to use OpenCV. We will later switch to Rasp Pi Camera. Do you have any knowledge about Rasp Pi Cameras Support on capturing in buffer? Also how can I delete saved images ?

Comment: Delete saved image you can on signal QCameraImageCapture::imageSaved(). About RaspPi cameras I can't help

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the QCamera backend. I believe that bug you are describing exists in GStreamer camerabin plugin. When you look to https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/src/plugins/gstreamer/camerabin/camerabinsession.cpp?h=5.15#n587 `m_imageFileName` is setup independently on capture destination. File is saved by this filter then https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/src/plugins/gstreamer/mediacapture/qgstreamercapturesession.cpp?h=5.15#n404

edit: this bug seems to be fixed in Qt 5.15